# Run PHP when node and/or profile is updated?

Tags: 7, hooks, users, nodes

I wanted to run an external script when a user profile(2) is updated, and/or when a node is updated. I've added the code to the themes template.php, but no go.

What have I missed?

```
<?php

$api_script_url = "http://www.aaa.com/test/test.php";
$msg = "File updated.";

// WHen a node is updated, be it new or old, update file.
function theme_node_update($node) {
    include($api_script_url."?q=".$node->nid);
    drupal_set_message($msg, 'status');
}

// WHen user profile2 profile is updated, be it new or old, file.
function theme_profile2_update($profile) {
    include($api_script_url."?q=".$profile->uid);
    drupal_set_message($msg, 'status');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theming functions are the wrong place for something like that. To run some PHP code after an node or profile (thus entity) is updated you should use the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) or use the following hooks, [hook_entity_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7), [hook_entity_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7)

Comment: I'll give the entity_update a look. How do I run an external PHP script ( an URL ) from Rules?

Comment: Rules is a pretty advanced system. There are many tutorials out there such as [this](https://drupal.org/node/1866108). There is an action "Execute PHP Code" which then gives you a box where you can put code. Within that you can do include or any other way to run php code in another script

Comment: Tried hook_entity_update instead, but no change. I'll try to find that PHP code than instead, although I've never seen it before.

Comment: You need the PHP Filter module enabled to be able to see it. Maybe that's your problem. See discussion [here](https://drupal.org/node/964494).